# Blazor component used multiple times on a page is showing search result data in both components

Tags: blazor, blazor-component, fluxor

I created an autocomplete component (input box with a search button). When the user types something in, a list appears below the input box with the results.  This is all working fine, but when I use the component more than once on a given page, the results show up underneath both input boxes, not just the one I'm using.  I believe this is because the search results themselves are being stored in a Fluxor store and when it changes blazor detects the change in that state variable and populates both lists.  Is there a way to only show and update the list from the component the user is working with? Or do I need to create a list of results in my state store and pull out the appropriate one based on some key?

Comment: Without code, wild guess.  If you're using Fluxor, the state data is probably *Scoped*.  i.e. it's the same state data for all your autocomplete components.  How to solve it????  Without your implementation, I'd be wild guessing again.  Why are you using Fluxor for this? FYI -  see this answer for implementing Autocomplete - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77348334/13065781

Comment: Fluxor is in use in the entire application for state management. The autocomplete component already works perfectly (when one is on the screen at a time).  The question is do i store each autocomplete result in a different state variable or stop using it for this box, and just store it with the component?

Comment: Without code, I'm guessing.  My guess is that as you need to use an interface for your autocomplete and different interface implementing state objects for Fluxor .  Personal and no help here  - I use my own Flux implementation which solves this problem by implementing a keyed object store.

Comment: appreciate the input, will look into that